# Sails ORM doesn't understand numeric values?

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline, value-type

Well this should work, everything (when going through it) step by step works. Except the actual writing to the database. In my sails application I have a route to the following function:

```
add: function (req, res) {
    let params = req.allParams();
    let idx = params.event_id;
    let name = params.name;
    let sport = params.sport;
    let location = params.location;
    let idNr = Number(idx);
    let sportNr = Number(sport);
    let locationNr = Number(location);
    let dat = {
      name:name,
      id:idNr,
      sport:sportNr,
      location:locationNr
    };
    console.log(dat);

    Event.create(dat)
      .then(function (res){ return res.ok(); })
      .catch(function (err){
        console.log(err);
        return res.send(err);
      });
}
```

Really a simplistic function right? Yet on my "good" data it fails:

```
{
    "error": "E_VALIDATION",
    "status": 400,
    "summary": "2 attributes are invalid",
    "model": "Event",
    "invalidAttributes": {
        "location": [
            {
                "rule": "number",
                "message": "Value should be a number (instead of \"3\", which is a string)"
            }
        ],
        "sport": [
            {
                "rule": "number",
                "message": "Value should be a number (instead of \"2\", which is a string)"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How can this happen? I cleary am using `dat` which takes a numeric variation of the "sport" and "location". - Logging even shows that the dat is filled as expected with numeric values.

So it makes no sense at all that this fails; it shouldn't.

---

EDIT, the model is defined as:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    id: {
      type: 'number',
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    location: {
      type: 'number',
      required: true,
    },
    sport: {
      type: 'number',
      required: true
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: It's telling you that the value is a string and not a number. Try `console.log(typeof param.location)` in that add function. The string `"3"` is different from the number `3`. Raw HTTP parameters are always strings.

Comment: @Pointy yes and that's why I rebuild the parameters using  `let sportNr = Number(sport);` and `dat`. - Testing  `console.log(typeof dat.location)` shows `number`

Comment: Ah, yes; sorry I completely missed that.

Answer (score 1):

This issue appears to be a limitation of sails support for

```
type:'number'
```

From the official [sails documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes) on model attributes. The following attribute types are supported:

- string
- text
- integer
- float
- date
- datetime
- boolean
- binary
- array
- json
- mediumtext
- longtext
- objectid

As an alternative to using the javascript

```
Number()
```

function, you could consider using

```
parseInt()
```

for known integer values or

```
parsefloat()
```

for known floating point numbers.